# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'flowScope' resolved to null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, websphere-8, flow-scope

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /flow1/flow1.xhtml at line 17 and column 70 value="#{flowScope.value}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'flowScope' resolved to null.
```

I have `flow.xhtml` page from there i'm setting the value below like this :

```
<span id="param1FromFlow1">
     Flow bean param1Value:
     <h:inputText id="input" value="#{flowScope.value}" />
</span>
```

but implicit object `flowScope` not picking the 
server am getting error in websphere 8.0.0.7.

after i changed to page bean also .Page bean declare as @FlowScoped ,again am getting error below in the same page;
 javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /flow1/flow1.xhtml at line 17 and column 69 value="#{flow1Bean.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'flow1Bean' resolved to null

Here My bean :

```
package com.webage.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;


@Named
@FlowScoped("flow1")
public class Flow1Bean implements Serializable {

    public String cusName;
    public String city;
    public String getName() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    public String doReturnValue() {
        return "return1";
    }

    /**
     * @return the cusName
     */
    public String getCusName() {
        return cusName;
    }

    /**
     * @param cusName the cusName to set
     */
    public void setCusName(String cusName) {
        this.cusName = cusName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the city
     */
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    /**
     * @param city the city to set
     */
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

MY Xhtml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
<title>flow1</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
    content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Style"
        href="../theme/stylesheet.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
 <h:form styleClass="form" id="form1">
 <h1>First Page in Flow 1</h1>

        <p>
            <span id="param1FromFlow1">Flow bean
                param1Value:<h:inputText id="input" value="#{flow1Bean.name}" />
            </span>
        </p>

        <p></p>
        <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Next" styleClass="commandButton"
            id="button1" action="flow1a"></h:commandButton>
        <p></p>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Please heklp me on this.

Comment: Have you tried this `@Named("flowScope")` or `@Named("flow1Bean")` in the bean annotation?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me Omoro ,I have done like below  :      Still am getting same error                                                @Named("flow1Bean")
@FlowScoped("flow1")
public class Flow1Bean implements Serializable {

Comment: I have done like below :  @Named("flowScope") @FlowScoped("flow1") public class Flow1Bean implements Serializable { - that is also not working still the same error.

Comment: Based on the name flowscope `flow1` I assume that you have this directory structure `flow1/flow1.xhtml` in your web pages, right?

Comment: yes,"flow1/flow1.xhtml" directory structure.

Comment: could you please any one help on this?

Comment: I fixed the Problem now an facing Bean state is not saved in FlowScope.Here my bean code :                                            

@ManagedBean(name="flow1")
@FlowScoped(value = "flow1")
public class Flow1Bean implements Serializable {

 public String cusName;
 public String city;
    //here getter and setters 
       
}